# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(n^p)$ diverges for all $p>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Prove that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(n^p)$ diverges for all $p>0$.
This should be simple but I have been failing. My latest attempt is Cauchy's criterion.

Comment: See if you can show that there are arbitrarily large $n$ for which $\sin (n^p) > 1/2$, for instance. This is an "intuitively true" conjecture, but I cannot prove it off the top of my head.

Comment: I'm not even convinced that this is true... Where did you find this question? Are there additional restrictions (e.g. "p is an integer" - in which case I think I have a proof)?

Comment: @D.Thomine On page 147 of V. A. Zorich's "Mathematical Analysis I", exercise 5, question b): "the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin{\dfrac{1}{n^p}}$ converges only for $p>1$."

Comment: That's probably a mistake (I don't have the book at hand, so I can't confirm). The question should read "Let $p > 0$. Prove that the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} sin (n^{-p})$ converges if and only if $p > 1$", in which case it is a classical exercise.

Comment: Got this from Wolfram, not sure how to prove it but it might help: $$\sum_{n=0}^m\sin(n)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(m)-\cot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\cos(m)+\cot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: You can prove that the series is divergent for $p \in [-1,1]$, although with different methods depending on the sign of $p$. I think I have a good argument to show that it diverges for $p < 0$ whenever $p$ is rational. I have no idea about the general case.

Comment: @D.Thomine You're probably right about the misprint thing... But I think in that case I should go on for a full proof(or counter example, maybe, but I haven't been able to find one yet). Can you show me how you managed with the rational $p$s?

Comment: @IanMiller Sorry, but I don't see how that helps... $\sin(n)$ and $\sin{n^p}$seem really different

Comment: @AlexG. I don't think there will be...intuitively I think for sufficiently large $n$, $\left\lbrace\sin{n^p}\right\rbrace$ will eventually assume all numbers in $[-1,1]$, and the sequence will have no limit at all(i. e. divergent). And judging from the conclusion of the problem, this is exactly what we have to prove. However, this just reminded me of an exercise that says when you rotate a circle for all integral radians then the orbit of a fixed point will be dense in the circle. But now we're rotating the circle for $n^p$ radians. I'll see if this idea helps.

Answer (score 7):

Let $p > 0$ be an arbitrary real number. I claim that $\sin(n^p)$ does not converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Equivalently, $n^p$ does not converge to $0$ modulo $\pi$.

For any function $f(n)$ let $\Delta f(n) = f(n+1) - f(n)$. If $f(n)$ converges to $0$ mod $\pi$ then so does $\Delta f(n)$. Now for $f(n) = n^p$ we have $\Delta f(n) \approx p n^{p-1}$, $\Delta^2 f(n) \approx p (p-1) n^{p-2}$, etc. More precisely, by Newton's binomial theorem,
$$(n+1)^p - n^p = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \binom{p}{i} n^{p-i}.$$
Let $k = \lfloor p \rfloor$. One can check that the part of the series with $i > k$ has the overall form $o(1)$. Thus
$$\Delta(n^p) = p n^{p-1} + c_2 n^{p-2} + \cdots + c_k n^{p-k} + o(1)$$
for various constant coefficients $c_2, \dots, c_k$. Iterating, it follows that
$$\Delta^k(n^p) = (p)_k n^{p-k} + o(1),$$
where $(p)_k = p(p-1) \cdots (p-k+1)$. Thus the function $g(n) = (p)_k n^{p-k}$ tends to $0$ mod $\pi$, but this is impossible: since $\pi$ is irrational we must have $p > k$, but then $g(n) \to \infty$ while $\Delta g(n) \to 0$, so the range of $g$ is dense mod $\pi$.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the answer to the question, and I think it is a mistake in the question itself. Here are a few remarks.

So, when is $\sum_{n \geq 0} \sin (n^p)$ convergent?

- If $p < -1$: the series is absolutely convergent.

This is because $\sin (n^p) \sim n^p$, which is the main term of an absolutely convergent series.

- If $p \in [-1,0]$: the series diverges to $+ \infty$.

If $p \in [-1,0)$, we have $\sin (n^p) \sim n^p$, which is positive and the main term of a divergent series. If $p = 0$, the partial sums are $n \sin (1)$, which goes to infinity.

- If $p \in (0,1)$: the series is divergent.

We have $(n+1)^p - n^p \sim p n^{p-1}$. If $n^p \equiv x$, then $(n+1)^p - n^p \equiv p x^{1-\frac{1}{p}}$. In particular, since the steps are this small, for some constant $C$, for all $x$, you will find an $n$ such that $n^p$ is at distance at most $C p x^{1-\frac{1}{p}}$ of $x$. Next, take $x_k := \pi/2+2\pi k$; this gets you an increasing sequence of integers $n_k$ such that $\lim_{k \to + \infty} \sin (n_k^p) = 1$.

Since the sequence $(\sin (n^p))_{n \geq 0}$ does not converges to $0$, the series is divergent. My best guess is that the partial sums will oscillate more and more, so that the partial sums do not diverge to $+ \infty$ or $- \infty$.

- If $p \geq 1$ is rational: the series is divergent.

It is enough to prove that $\sin (n^p)$ does not converges to $0$. For any $n \geq 0$, write:

$$n^p = 2 \pi k_n + \varepsilon_n,$$

where $k_n$ is an integer and $\varepsilon_n \in [-\pi, \pi)$. Since $p$ is rational, there exists and integer $\lambda \geq 2$ such that $\lambda^p$ is an integer. Note that:

$$(\lambda^m n)^p = 2 \pi k_n \lambda^{mp} + \lambda^{mp} \varepsilon_n.$$

Since $\pi$ is transcendental, $\varepsilon_n \neq 0$ for all $n > 0$. Hence, 
I can find an integer $m$ such that $|\lambda^{mp} \varepsilon_n| \in [\lambda^{-p}\pi,\pi]$, so that:

$$|\sin ((\lambda^m n)^p)| \geq \sin (\lambda^{-p}\pi).$$

Hence, for any $n>0$, there exists $n' \geq n$ such that $|\sin ((n')^p)| \geq \sin (\lambda^{-p}\pi)$. I can then construct recursively an increasing sequence of integers $(n_k)_{k \geq 0}$ such that $|\sin (n_k^p)| \geq \sin (\lambda^{-p}\pi)$ for all $k$, and the sequence $(\sin (n^p))_{n \geq 0}$ does not converge to $0$.

- In general: I have no idea. There may be strange phenomena if we tune $p$ (see e.g. Mill's constant for a related construction).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simple to see that the limit $\lim_{\infty}\sin{n^p}$ does mot go to $0$ (does not even exists) therefore the series 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sin{n^p}$$ diverges.

**Recall**

For every converging series $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$ we have $a_n\to 0,~~$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: It's natural for one to guess so but rather hard to actually *prove* it, especially for irrational $p$'s; as we see in the answer from Thomine, it is not trivial.